# nodejs: verify username existence on facebook

Tags: node.js

I am trying to verify the existence of a facebook username using `nodejs` using the `hapijs` framework by sending an http request to facebook plus the username I want to search for. 
So `"http://wwww.facebook.com/"+req.params.username`
And depending on the status code that is returned determine if the username is available or not. However, for facebook, a 200 status code is always returned.
What do I have to do to get around this and get a `404` for a username that does not exist?

Comment: It seems facebook redirect to facebook.com (login page) if you aren t connected. May it be the problem? Check the body of the response, you should try to connect your app to facebook before doing that.

Comment: @MMRibot I think FB uses .htaccess to profiles. Therefore they do not set any status code for the page

Comment: @MMRibot you can use `graph API` of facebook, make `get` request to `"http://graph.facebook.com/"+username`, it returns JSON.

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to ask the user to authenticate using facebook? So you could also be sure that it's an active account.

Comment: @Ravi thanks. I was looking into that yesterday, but was not sure I was looking into the right thing.